# Typesetting characters across several rows in a table

Tags: tables

You will see in the following example there are curly brackets that span two rows of this table:

[image]

Is there a way to generate this kind of typesetting in the basic table environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`bigdelim`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bigdelim):

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{multirow,bigdelim}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lccr}
\toprule
text & \ldelim\{{3}{0pt} & 6 & text \\
text & & 3 & text \\
text & & 8 & text \\
text & \ldelim\{{3}{0pt} & 7 & text \\
text & & 4 & text \\
text & & 2 & text \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]