# Curly brackets in table cell for language manual

Tags: tables, brackets

I try to make a table for language manual. Could anybody help me to manage curly brackets in the cells of a table?

Like this:

[image]

I tried to do it like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156936/typesetting-characters-across-several-rows-in-a-table) but I could't manage it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution with `blkarray` allows to have vertically aligned braces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx, blkarray}
\newcommand\colhead[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{$}c<{$}}{#1}}
\usepackage{eqparbox} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|lp{\eqboxwidth{C}}@{}|}
\hline
 & \\
 \begin{blockarray}{l}
 \begin{block}{l\Right{\}}{\eqmakebox[C]{\hskip-0.7emREAD}}}
    I\\
    You\\
    We\\
    They\\
\end{block}\\[-2ex]
 \begin{block}{l\Right{\}}{\eqmakebox[C]{READS}}}
 She\\
 He\\
 It\\
\end{block}
  \end{blockarray} & \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

An example with `\right\}` for the curly brace and a table inside a table:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{tabular}{|l|}
\hline
  $\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\left.
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    I\\
    You\\
    We\\
    They
  \end{tabular}\right\}$ read
\\
  $\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\left.
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    He\\
    She\\
    It
  \end{tabular}\right\}$ reads
\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]