# Grouping contents of a table using curly brackets

Tags: tables

I have a table and want to group the contents using curly brackets as shown in the figure using latex tabular environment. Can someone help me this? [image: for example: 4 to 1 should be grouped as A, 0 as B, -1 to -3 as C and -4 to -5 as D]

```
\begin{table}[!h]
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline

Score& Description\\
\hline

+4 &Playing\\
+3& Walking\\
+2& Crawling\\
+1 &Restless\\
+0& Calm\\
-1 &Sleep1\\
-2 &sleep2\\
-3 &sleep3\\
-4 &dream1\\
-5 &dream2\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

\end{table}

Comment: You could make it easier for answerers if you would post the code of your table which you already have. So not everybody needs to type all again. And we would see the column types.

Comment: Possible duplicate(s): [Curly brackets in table cell for language manual](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/180196/5764); [Typesetting characters across several rows in a table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/156936/5764)